# How come $a_1$ is not equal to $s_1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm given a partial sum $s_n=3-n*2^{-n}$ of a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and my task is to calculate  $a_n$.

So, knowing that $a_n=s_n - s_{n-1}$, I get the result $a_n= \frac{(n-2)}{(2^n)}$. I wanted to check if my term is correct, so I decided to make a simple substitution:
$$s_1=3-1*2^{-1}=3-\frac{1}{2}=2 \frac{1}{2}$$
$$a_1=\frac{(1-2)}{2^1}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

The result is somehow different. How are they not equal?

Thanks!

Comment: Because it's impossible for the sum of no terms $s_0=3$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You have $a_1=s_1-s_0=s_1-3$

Comment: Because your formula is true for $\;n\ge 2\;$ ...and you should be given $\;a_1\;$ . Obser ve that $\;a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}\;$ is true for $\;n\ge2\;$ .

Comment: OP please listen to @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's clear now!